# In fclose function, which one added lock logic code?

Tags: c, glibc

While I analyze **fclose** function in my binary, I found some strange logic in gdb.

Assembly code below is lock logic before `_IO_file_close_it` function is started.

```
   ...
   0x7f50cc7c140a <fclose+218>     mov    esi, 0x1
 → 0x7f50cc7c140f <fclose+223>     xor    eax, eax
   0x7f50cc7c1411 <fclose+225>     cmp    DWORD PTR [rip+0x3725c0], 0x0        # 0x7f50ccb339d8 <__libc_multiple_threads>
   0x7f50cc7c1418 <fclose+232>     je     0x7f50cc7c1422 <_IO_new_fclose+242>
   0x7f50cc7c141a <fclose+234>     lock   cmpxchg DWORD PTR [rdx], esi
   ...
   ...
```

But, when I searched original source in [this_link](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/libio/iofclose.c.html), this `lock` logic was not found...

```c
// glibc-2.23/libio/iofclose.c:37

int
_IO_new_fclose (_IO_FILE *fp)
{
  int status;

  CHECK_FILE(fp, EOF);

#if SHLIB_COMPAT (libc, GLIBC_2_0, GLIBC_2_1)
  /* We desperately try to help programs which are using streams in a
     strange way and mix old and new functions.  Detect old streams
     here.  */
  if (_IO_vtable_offset (fp) != 0)
    return _IO_old_fclose (fp);
#endif

  /* First unlink the stream.  */
  if (fp->_IO_file_flags & _IO_IS_FILEBUF)
    _IO_un_link ((struct _IO_FILE_plus *) fp);

  _IO_acquire_lock (fp);
  if (fp->_IO_file_flags & _IO_IS_FILEBUF)
    status = _IO_file_close_it (fp);
  else
    status = fp->_flags & _IO_ERR_SEEN ? -1 : 0;
  _IO_release_lock (fp);
  _IO_FINISH (fp);

  /*
    Where is logic that compares multiple threads and executes lock???
  */
  ...
  ...
```

So, I guessed this logic is pushed when **compile time** and searched about this phenomenon.

But, There is no explanation about this. Did I miss any codes in .c file?

*Summary*

- I wanna know which one added these assembly code that compare "__libc_multi_threads" and executes "lock".

Comment: Are you sure the source code you're looking at matches the disassembled code?

Comment: After chasing a few macros starting at `_IO_acquire_lock`, we find `_IO_lock_lock` in glibc. It seems to be be comparing some thread variables. https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/sysdeps/nptl/stdio-lock.h.html , line 40

Comment: @gspr Thank you and sorry for checking late. As you chased, `_IO_acquire_lock` is defined in **stdio-lock.h** file. But, how connect `_IO_acquire_lock` to `_IO_lock_lock` ? 
`_IO_lock_lock` is not in `_IO_acquire_lock` ... Am i wrong?